# Select2: set hidden field value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I have the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="airport" tabindex="6" />


$('input[name="airport"]', '#details-form').select2({
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            multiple: true,
            separator: ';',
            width: 'off',
            initSelection : function (element, callback) {
                var data = [];
                $(element.val().split(';')).each(function () {
                    data.push({id: this, text: this});
                });
                callback(data);
            },
            ajax: { 
                url: History.getBasePageUrl() + 'get-airports-dictionary',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        q: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    var code = parseInt(data[0]);
                    switch (code) {
                        case 0: 
                            return {results: data[1]};
                            break;
                        default:
                            window.Common.showError(data[1]);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            },
            formatResult: formatAirportResult,
            formatSelection: formatAirportSelection
        });
```

Everything works fine untill I want to set an existing value for that field - the element argument inside initSelection method shows empty value!

```
$('input[name="airport"]', '#details-form').select2('val', '2');
```

I tried to set the original value with the following code:

```
$('input[name="airport"]', '#details-form').val('2');
```

It works, but somewhere inside select2's val method the value dissapears..

I use version 3.4.0 of Select2 with [this update](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/commit/dae97ffc8372287abd3158acae0307a75189e36c).

Thank you

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/112

Comment: @mccannf nope, they talk about array data and I use ajax query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the working solution:

```
$('input[name="airport"]', '#details-form').select2({
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            multiple: true,
            separator: ';',
            width: 'off',
            initSelection : function (element, callback) {
                var data = [];
                $(element.val().split(',')).each(function(i) {
                    var item = this.split(':');
                    data.push({
                        id: item[0],
                        label: item[1]
                    });
                });
                callback(data);
            },
            ajax: { 
                url: History.getBasePageUrl() + 'get-airports-dictionary',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        q: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    var code = parseInt(data[0]);
                    switch (code) {
                        case 0: 
                            return {results: data[1]};
                            break;
                        default:
                            window.Common.showError(data[1]);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            },
            formatResult: formatAirportResult,
            formatSelection: formatAirportSelection
        });
        function formatAirportResult(item) {
            return item.label + ' <strong class="pull-right">' + item.code + '</strong>';
        }
        function formatAirportSelection(item) {
            return item.label;
        }
```

I don't know why, but value argument can't be string - in order to make it work it has to be an array of strings.. Otherwise select2 sets empty value to input field.

```
$('input[name="airport"]', '#details-form').select2('val', ['2:Domodedovo', '3:Vnukovo']);
```

Proof - http://jsfiddle.net/GZyeb/1/