# Select2 val returning all available tags instead of selected tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have been using Select2 multi-select for selecting and add tags to a tag cloud. It was previously working fine, but now the line to return selected tags is returning all available tags.

I need to emphasize that this is for multi-select not single select.

This is the code I use to make use of the Select2 multi-select:

```
$('#Tags').select2({
    val: toSelect,
    createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function() {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            return {
                id: term,
                text: term,
                count: 1
            };
        }
    },
    multiple: true,
    data: data,
    tokenSeparators: [","],
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "Enter tag"
});
```

where toSelect is an array of already assigned tags to a particular item.

This is the line that is not working:

```
var tagsdata = $("#Tags").select2("val");
```

The element Tags look like this:

```
 <div type="hidden" id="Tags" style="width:300px" />
```

Does anyone have an idea why it is doing so?

Comment: I read a previous question on SO that says to use input / div, not a select element? Also, it was originally as an input, but it wouldn't show up and so also another question on SO said use a div and then it worked....

Comment: I will find the direct ones, but for example here is an example using an input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686849/select2-set-hidden-field-value

Comment: I need support for multi-select, so a `select` is not going to work for that anyway.